# What could cause a "Runtime Error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument" when running a VB 6 executable?

Tags: vb6

I have an existing VB 6 project, but I had to change the design and after changing the design I could save the updated code but could not reflect the changes in the exe file as the existing exe file can't be edited. How do I do this? I tried to move the existing exe file to another location and save new exe file but when I run the new one I get the following error:

> Runtime error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument.

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Since you're getting a **run-time error**, the problem almost certainly lies with your source code. If you run the application from the VB 6 environment, the debugger should break whenever the run-time error occurs and highlight the lines responsible. If you could post that section of your code, we could be much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be as simple as passing a value that is outside the accepted range for a function, property, etc.